# Show and hide based on time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show and hide a series of `div`s based on time interval.

Show div 1 after 4 seconds, show div 2 after a further 4 seconds and so on.

The previous `div` being hidden, so it appears as if new information is replacing the previous and at time intervals.

I have it working to a point, it's just when I add more `div`s.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#a").hide();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#b").fadeIn('normal');
  });
}, 4000);
```

```css
#b, #c {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
<div id="c">3</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Layt8cuy/1/

The first `div` needs to be there by default, and they stop with the last `div` with no loop back to the beginning.

Comment: Have you thought about changing the content of a single div rather than showing and hiding multiple div's?

Comment: I would advise to use css keyframes instead, we can set various timers in a simple way with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is basic function [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Layt8cuy/31/)

```js
var currentDiv = $("#a");
var nextDiv, count = 1;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (count == 5) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  } else {
    count++;
    currentDiv.hide();
    currentDiv = currentDiv.next();
    currentDiv.show();
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
#b,
#c,
#d,
#e {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
<div id="c">3</div>
<div id="d">4</div>
<div id="e">5</div>
```

Comment: Yeah nearly there, just no loop needed, when it gets to the last one, thats it ended, that would be great :-)

Comment: @John Update my answer can u check pls.

Comment: Every time you add or remove `div`s, you'll have to change the `count` in code. It is better to get the number of `div`s dynamically.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't mean to break the questioner's code. @RacilHilan

Answer (score 3):

You need a variable to track the current visible `div`. Also it's recommended to use a class to select all `div`s, otherwise you'll have to select them by tag name, which is an issue if you have other `div`s that shouldn't be included.

You only need `setInterval()` and inside it first hide all `div`s, then show the `div` with the current index, and finally increment the current index variable if it is still less that the number of `div`s, otherwise reset it to 0.

```js
var current = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var divs = $(".roll").hide();
  divs.eq(current).fadeIn("normal");
  if (current < divs.length - 1)
    current++;
  else
    current = 0;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.roll {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="roll">1</div>
<div id="b" class="roll">2</div>
<div id="c" class="roll">3</div>
```

To do only one loop, you need to store the ID of the `setInterval()` and use it in `clearInterval()` to stop. Here is a solution for the points in your comments:

```js
var current = 0;

var divs = $(".roll");
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (current < divs.length - 1) {
    divs.eq(current).hide();
    current++;
    divs.eq(current).fadeIn("normal");
  } else
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.roll {
  display: none
}

#a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="roll">1</div>
<div id="b" class="roll">2</div>
<div id="c" class="roll">3</div>
```

Comment: I need them coming in at staggered times and with no loop back to the beginning. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: What does "staggered times" mean here? If you don't want to loop, then instead of resetting the index, use `clearInterval()` to stop. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, thats nearly there, the only issue is the first div '1' needs to be there by default, rather than fading in?

Comment: You really need to describe all the requirements in your question, instead of in comments bit by bit. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

a working example, with returning to first div after finish
**recursive + timeout**
you can use the same method for your situation:

```js
let duration = 1000, // these are miliseconds
  activeIndex = 0;  // first item to activate

function activateNext() {
  let boxes = $('.boxes > div');

  // activate current item
  boxes.addClass('hide').eq(activeIndex).removeClass('hide');
  
  // increase activeIndex and make reset at end of collection 
  if (++activeIndex >= boxes.length) activeIndex = 0;
  
  // run the function again after duration
  setTimeout(function() {
    activateNext(activeIndex);
  }, duration)
}

// start the loop
$(window).on('load', activateNext);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

**Without looping back to first:**

```js
let duration = 1000, // these are miliseconds
  activeIndex = 0;  // first item to activate

function activateNext() {
  let boxes = $('.boxes > div');

  // activate current item
  boxes.addClass('hide').eq(activeIndex).removeClass('hide');
  
  // increase activeIndex and make reset at end of collection 
  if (++activeIndex < boxes.length) {
  
  // run the function again after duration
  setTimeout(function() {
    activateNext(activeIndex);
  }, duration)
  }
}

// start the loop
$(window).on('load', activateNext);
```

```css
  .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="boxes">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider pure *CSS* solution:

```css
#a, #b, #c {
  position: absolute;
  animation: hide 4s linear forwards;
}

#b, #c {opacity: 0}

#b {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#c {
  animation-name: last;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes hide {
  0%, 99.99% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 0}
}

@keyframes last {
  0%, 100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
<div id="c">3</div>
```

Comment: How do i repeat the animation in loop ?